# getContentList does not return videos

Tags: api, camera, sony

I've created a project which collects videos and images from a sony camera. To do this, I start the "Smart Remote Control" app on the camera using the camera's physical controls. I connect a computer to the camera's broadcasted wifi, then call the following rest resources with params in order:

**/sony/camera**

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "method" : "setCameraFunction",
    "params" : ['Contents Transfer'],
    "version" : "1.0"
}
```

**/sony/avContent**

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "method" : "getContentList",
    "params" : [{ 'uri': 'storage:memoryCard1', 'stIdx': 0, 'cnt': 100, 'view': 'flat', 'sort' : 'descending'}],
    "version" : "1.3"
}
```

The response from /avContent when using the Sony A7s ii is a list of both videos and photos. When using the older Sony A7s (not ii), I only get a list of photos even though there are saved videos. Do I have some kind of settings or permissions set incorrectly on the camera? Or is there another problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the A7S is one of the cameras that does not support movie transferring.  You can see on the footnote 21 from this page: https://developer.sony.com/develop/cameras/

ILCE-7, ILCE-7R, ILCE-5000, ILCE-5100, ILCE-6000, NEX-5R, NEX-5T, NEX-6, DSC-HX60 and DSC-HX400 don’t support the APIs group. AVCHD movie is not supported. ILCE-7S and DSC-RX100M3 support only still images. ILCE-7M2 doesn’t support remote playback API group.

Comment: Is there any plan in the future to support those api groups on the devices you listed below?

Comment: Is there any other way to automate media retrieval from the device?